# Browse by tags, how can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, tags

I like the browse by tag implementation on SO, I think it is quite good, having said that, I keep on thinking there are some ways of improving it.

What changes would you make to the browse by tag UI to make it easier to find stuff?

Some ideas (most of them are probably rubbish, but good for a brain storm):

- Multi tag selection
- Hierarchy
- Merge in untagged content that has the same keywords in the body
- A different UI layout
- Live preview of answers

Comment: Multi tag selection kind of exists in the search feature when you input, for example "[C#] [jquery] pointer" to target C# and jquery tags; however I see what you mean for browsing - the ability to pin down more than one tag button on the UI would be another useful implementation of that same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Digg Labs](http://labs.digg.com/) has some interesting visualization features for popular, current, active content etc. That could translate into SO as visualization of tags, tagged stories even high-voted Q&As, tag activity, bounty hunts, etc.